# Set columns to null or empty in JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

**Order Table**

```
ORDER_ID|ORDER_DT
1       |12-12-2016
```

**Product Table**

```
PRODUCT ID | ORDER ID
1          | 1
2          | 1
```

using `SELECT * FROM order o LEFT JOIN product p ON o.order_id = p.order_id;`

results

```
 PRODUCT ID | ORDER ID|ORDER_DT
 1          | 1       |12-12-2016
 2          | 1       |12-12-2016
 3          | 1       |12-12-2016
```

but I need to have this kind of results,noticed that I have still the same nos. of rows but duplicates in order table columns was emptied.

```
PRODUCT ID | ORDER ID|ORDER_DT
     1     | 1       |12-12-2016
     2     |         |
     3     |         |
```

Comment: This is more of a display thing that you would do at your presentation layer, not in your database.

Comment: You're missing the "ON" condition in your join clause so you are getting a cartesian product. (Or you would if you had more than one order in your database!)

Comment: Sorry updated question @LordPeter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with temoorary variables, e.g.:

```
SELECT product_id, orders.order_id, order_dt, IF(@previous = orders.order_id, 0, orders.order_id) AS oid, @previous:= orders.order_id
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products
ON orders.order_id = products.order_id,
(SELECT @previous := -1) a;
```

And wrap it into another `SELECT` query to get the required columns, e.g.:

```
SELECT r.product_id, IF(r.oid = 0, '', r.oid) AS order_id, r.order_dt 
FROM (
    SELECT product_id, orders.order_id, order_dt, IF(@previous = orders.order_id, 0, orders.order_id) AS oid, @previous:= orders.order_id
    FROM orders
    LEFT JOIN products
    ON orders.order_id = products.order_id,
    (SELECT @previous := -1) a
    ) r;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7907f/2/0)**.